# Spring Data REST / Spring Data Commons Domain Events

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest, spring-data-commons

I read this [blog](https://spring.io/blog/2017/01/30/what-s-new-in-spring-data-release-ingalls) and this [reference material](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#context-functionality-events-annotation) and determined that the Spring Data Commons Domain Events does not work when applied within Spring Data REST AbstractRepositoryEventListener events (i.e., onBeforeSave, onAfterDelete, etc).

**Person:**

```
@Entity @Data @EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=true)
public class Person extends AbstractEntity {
  // impl

  public void markComplete(){
    registerEvent(new PersonCompletedEvent());
  }
}
```

**PersonCompletedEvent:**

```
@Data public class PersonCompletedEvent {} // the RestBucks sample does not have OrderPaid event extend ApplicationEvent, I tried both ways and it still doesn't work.
```

**Update:** Read the comment in PersonHandler, it's the reason why application events do not work in this example.

**PersonHandler:**

```
@Component @RepositoryEventHandler public class PersonHandler {

  @PersistenceContext private EntityManager entityManager;
  @Autowired private PersonRepo personRepo;

  @HandleBeforeSave public void beforeSave(Person afterPerson){

     /* UPDATE ::: This is the problem.
      * This line is the reason why applicatin events do not fire.
      * I need the before entity to detect delta's in the domain 
      * so I must detach it. However this causes events to be dropped.
      *
      * What's the best way to get the previous state?
      */
     entityManager.detach(afterPerson); 
     Person beforePerson = personRepo.findOne(afterPerson.getId());

     // impl
     if (some condition) {
       afterPerson.markComplete(); // this does add the event but it's never fired.
     }
  }
}
```

**AbstractEntity:**

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.AbstractAggregateRoot;
@MappedSuperclass @Data @EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class AbstractEntity extends AbstractAggregateRoot implements Identifiable<Long> {
  // impl
}
```

**PersonListener:**

```
public class PersonListener {
  @EventListener
  public void processCompleted(PersonCompletedEvent event) {
    // THIS IS NEVER FIRED
  }
}
```

I've debugged this extensively and it looks like the DomainEvents are getting dropped somewhere between [RepositoryEntityController](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/spring-data-rest-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/RepositoryEntityController.java#L444) and [EventPublishingRepositoryProxyPostProcessor$EventPublishingMethodInterceptor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/repository/core/support/EventPublishingRepositoryProxyPostProcessor.java#L82).

What's really happening is that a different instance of my Entity is actually being intercepted and at that point the DomainEvents are no longer there. I can confirm that @AfterDomainEventPublication clearDomainEvents() is NOT being called at this time which leads me to believe it has something to do with the domainEvents being transient.

Spring Data REST's [RepositoryEntityController](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/spring-data-rest-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/RepositoryEntityController.java#L444) looks like this:

```
private ResponseEntity<ResourceSupport> saveAndReturn(Object domainObject, RepositoryInvoker invoker,
            HttpMethod httpMethod, PersistentEntityResourceAssembler assembler, boolean returnBody) {

  publisher.publishEvent(new BeforeSaveEvent(domainObject));  // 1
  Object obj = invoker.invokeSave(domainObject);              // 2
  publisher.publishEvent(new AfterSaveEvent(obj));
```

After executing line commented with 1 my domainObject has domainEvents and that's what goes into the line commented with 2, invokeSave. When my breakpoint catches at [RepositoryEntityController](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/spring-data-rest-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/RepositoryEntityController.java#L444) and [EventPublishingRepositoryProxyPostProcessor$EventPublishingMethodInterceptor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/repository/core/support/EventPublishingRepositoryProxyPostProcessor.java#L82) it's actually a different instance of my object (different object id) and the only thing missing is the domainEvents and nothing get's fired.

**Update: Read my comment below, it's not working because the entity is detached.**

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: @JensSchauder, I know I'm a bit vague in this post but the general question / problem is that the Spring Application Event's are not firing in this example and I found the root problem (I've updated this post to reflect that). I need to detect state changes with my entity's because that drives business logic and the only way I see to get the before entity here is to detach it from the persistence context...but by doing so the events won't fire. I think I need to take a completely different approach to this.

Comment: It's not that it is vague. To be honest it is messy. I'd recommend rewriting the complete question and give it some clear structure: What do you do; What do you expect; What does happen; What is the actual question (bold, ending in a question mark); All relevant source code; Bonus points for a link to a repo on which one can run mvn clean install and gets a test failure.

Comment: Regarding this question: What's the best way to get the previous state? This issue might be of interest: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-373